# Tackling old challenges with new, legitimate technology

Tags: discussion

Right now we have a rule in place that limits answers to language implementations that were made *before* the question was posted. This makes sense, because otherwise I could invent a programming language after a certain problem was posted that solves the problem in 0 bytes.

However, I feel like another facet of this issue has been left undiscussed so far: old questions.

Languages change over time, and new (legitimate) languages are constructed all the time. If I want to post an answer to a year old question however, I must track down which version of my preferred programming language I can use, if I can use my language at all! This is especially problematic for esolangs, which often don't have such... rigorous versioning.

Should we perhaps lax the restraints for new languages/versions for old questions? If yes, how?

Comment: If you want to solve the questions just for fun, then sure, go ahead and post a submission in a language/feature developed after the question was asked. The only caveat is that this submissions cannot be accepted. Its a perfectly valid submission otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

I think nobody cares if you use a newer version of a 'ordinary' language. The only thing we want to prevent with this rule is - what you already said - that people come up with a new 'esolang' that is just designed for one specific challenge. I think the use of some common sense can be expected here.

Comment: Even if you were to create an esolang designed specifically for the challenge, that is a [loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1071/40695) disallowed by default.